# Get Current Visible Fragment From Activity

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

In my (now deprecated) `ActionBarActivity`, I want to find out what `Fragment` is visible so I can call a method inside the correct one.

I am doing it like this but it says I cannot cast `Fragment` with any of the 3 Custom `Fragments` I created:

```
if (requestCode == 99) {
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_frag);
    if (f instanceof GasFragment) {
        // call method
    } else if (f instanceof OilFragment) {
        // call method
    } else if (f instanceof VehicleFragment) {
        // call method 
    }
}
```

I have added a tag name for each `Fragment` so I was also researching a "find `fragment` by `tag`" and have not found anything on that front either.

Basically the code above is inside `onActivityResult`.  I catch a result and then do the above block of code.

---

**NOTE**: The above code was my second method to accomplishing the same thing But I have gotten neither option to work.  Originally, I opened a `SettingsActivity` inside my Nav Drawer and used a `startActivityFromResult()`.  I wanted the result to be caught inside the open `Fragment` to call the relevant method.  However, I was unable to catch the result from the `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult()` so I decided to do the above code block in the parent's `ActionBarActivity` `onActivityResult()` instead.

If this plan is a more efficient idea, I'd accept that answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose all your Fragments are extending from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

In this case, you have to use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()`, as `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` will return a `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: Aaarrgghh!! dumb dumb dumb.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In you fragment, you need to override `setMenuVisibility` method and save the boolean passed in. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setMenuVisibility(boolean))
Now just implement a common interface in all fragments that allows activity to ask the fragments if they are visibile and you can then cast them by the way.